# Deployment of OpenBravo to Jboss Wildfly error

Tags: java, wildfly, openbravo, wildfly-9

I am trying to deploy a custom build of OpenBravo3.0 to JBoss Wildfly wildfly-9.0.2.Final.

The OpenBravo source is downloaded at http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Installation/Custom/Download_Tarball and I did an ant build by issuing ant compile.complete.deploy. The ant command outputs a war build named openbravo.war at lib/ directory.

However, the war cannot be deployed due to this error:

```
12:23:59,959 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4)     WFLYWELD0009: Starting weld service for deployment openbravo.war
12:24:03,368 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./openbravo.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./openbravo.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: Failed to start service
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT010009: Servlet P037C0E9B93984960BABB84F35C38975E of type class org.openbravo.erpCommon.ad_process.KillSession does not implement javax.servlet.Servlet
at io.undertow.servlet.api.ServletInfo.<init>(ServletInfo.java:98)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:695)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.start(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:265)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
... 3 more

12:24:03,377 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "openbravo.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./openbravo.UndertowDeploymentInfoService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./openbravo.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: Failed to start service
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT010009: Servlet P037C0E9B93984960BABB84F35C38975E of type class org.openbravo.erpCommon.ad_process.KillSession does not implement javax.servlet.Servlet"}}
```

Is it possible to use a non-servlet class such as KillSession as a servlet?

```
package org.openbravo.erpCommon.ad_process;

import org.openbravo.dal.service.OBDal;
import org.openbravo.erpCommon.utility.OBError;
import org.openbravo.model.ad.access.Session;
import org.openbravo.scheduling.Process;
import org.openbravo.scheduling.ProcessBundle;

/**
 * This process kills the session passed in the AD_Session_ID parameter.
 * 
 */
public class KillSession implements Process {
...
...
}


package org.openbravo.scheduling;

/**
 * All Openbravo Processes that require scheduling through the {@link OBScheduler} or monitoring
 * through the {@link ProcessMonitor} are required to implement this interface.
 * 
 * @author awolski
 * 
 */
public interface Process {
...
...
}


<servlet>
  <display-name>
    org.openbravo.erpCommon.ad_process.KillSession
  </display-name>
  <servlet-name>
    P037C0E9B93984960BABB84F35C38975E
  </servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
    org.openbravo.erpCommon.ad_process.KillSession
  </servlet-class>


</servlet>
```

Comment: http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/System_Requirements#Server:_software_stack ... These r the officially supported server stack.

Comment: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/220111?tstart=0&_sscc=t

Comment: @Vel, Thanks. Looks like Wildfly is not supported.